# Unable to Override onRequestPermissionResult in Xamarin-Android

Tags: android, exception, xamarin, overriding

newbie in **Xamarin** here. I was unable to run my app because **Camera was throwing an exception** whenever I tried to open it for permission issues, so I followed the documentation about ***requesting permission in runtime***, but it says that I have to override the onRequestPermissionResult method, but the compiler says:

> The word @Override does not exist in the current context

[As you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KHHl.png)

If I use the override keyword between the method, I mean,

> public override onRequestPermissionResult

I'm getting another error:

> No suitable method found to override.

I don't know if it is a problem of inheritance, but I cannot make the class to inherit from anything more because it already inherits from PageRenderer class. Sorry if it's a dumb question but after a long research I couldn't figure out how to solve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't post images of your code, post the code itself. Also add more code of the class which you try to do it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Xamarin.Forms right? If so, you need to use `DependencyService` and request for permission in Android project.

And it should be `OnRequestPermissionsResult` not `onRequestPermissionResult`

```
public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Permission[] grantResults)
{
    base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can enable Camera Permission in your android manifest by adding this line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.Camera" />
```

If you need it specifically at runtime:

```
string[] PermissionsCamera =
    {
                  Manifest.Permission.Camera

        };
             int RequestId = 0;
            if (this.CheckSelfPermission(PermissionsCamera[0]) == (int)Permission.Granted)
            {
                // permission already granted

            }

            else
            {
                // request permissions
                Activity.RequestPermissions(PermissionsCamera, RequestId);
            }
        }
```

To get feedback, you override OnRequestPermissionsResult:

```
public override  void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            switch (requestCode)
            {
                case RequestId:
                    {
                        if (grantResults[0] == Permission.Granted)
                        {
                            //Permission granted

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //Permission Denied :

                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Hope this helps